# How to align MUI expandable icons to the end of the DataGrid?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, mui-datatable, mui-x-data-grid

I am trying to align the expandable/ collapsable icons to the right side of the DataGridPremium. I have used SX prop but it does not work. Not sure if it needs to be done at the 'rows' level or on the component prop iteself. Please see image

[image]

Current code is

```
                   <DataGridPremium
                    getDetailPanelContent={({row}) => <div>Row ID: {row.id}</div>}
                    slots={{
                        detailPanelExpandIcon: ExpandMoreIcon, //Slots used for icons
                        detailPanelCollapseIcon: ExpandLessIcon,
                    }}
                    rows={filteredRows}
                    columns={selectedColumns}
                    getRowId={(row) => row.id}
                    pageSizeOptions={[5, 10, 15, 100]}
                    checkboxSelection
                    sx={{
                        '& .MuiDataGrid-detailPanelToggleCell': {
                            display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'flex-end',
                        }
                    }}
                />

 //example data structure for rows


const rows = [{
id: 1, 
uuid: '1a9072ca-ca3d-4b9b-9626-14b31743a3cb', 
first_name: 'Mohsin', 
last_name: 'Miah', 
display_name: 'Moh'
}]
```

Columns and Rows populated as follows

```
if (users.length > 0) {
    // Populate columns
    const keys = Object.keys(users[0]);
    columns = keys.map((key) => ({
        field: key,
        headerName: key.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + key.slice(1).replace(/_/g, ' '),
        width: 180,
        GRID_DETAIL_PANEL_TOGGLE_COL_DEF
    }));
    // Populate rows
    rows = users.map((user, index) => ({
        id: index + 1,
        ...user
    }));
}
```

Any help on this would be great. I've checked the MUI docs which mentions using slotProps property but I couldnt seem to make sense of it!